# Knowing $|A| \leq |B|$, how do I prove $|C^A| \leq |C^B|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given three (nonempty) sets $A, B$ and $C$, and knowing that $|A| \leq |B|$, how can I prove that $|C^A| \leq |C^B|$? This problem is trivial if we want to prove that the sets are equipotent, because it is very easy to create a bijective function.

Here, we know that there exists an *injective* function $\phi: A \rightarrow B$, and we have to construct another injection, $\psi: C^A \rightarrow C^B$. I came up with this: let $f: A \rightarrow C$ and $b \in B$; then

$(\psi(f))(b) = 
\begin{cases}
f(a)  & \exists \,a \in A \;\; \phi(a) = b\\
??? & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

But I couldn't figure out what to do in the second case (which is very possible because we know that $A \subseteq B$). Intuitively, it is rather obvious that if we have less elements in $A$ than in $B$, then less functions transforming $A$ into $C$ exist, but of course some sort of formal proof is needed.

Since I don't know how standard that notation is, I'd like to clarify that $A^B$ denotes the set of all possible functions transforming elements of $B$ into elements of $A$.

Comment: Fix some $c_0\in C$, and replace $???$ with $c_0$. This will be the desired injection.

Comment: @Guy I should've thought of that... If you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\left|A\right|\leq\left|B\right|$, we have an injection $\phi:A\to B$. Fix some $c_0\in C$ and define
$$\psi:C^A\to C^B$$
by
$$\left(\psi\left(f\right)\right)\left(b\right)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\phi\left(a\right)&\exists a\in A:\phi\left(a\right)=b\\c_0&\textrm{Otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$$
This is the desired injection.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using the Axiom of Choice, here's an alternative to using an injection $A\to B$.

By assumption, $A\ne\emptyset$. Thus $\lvert A\rvert \le \lvert B\rvert$ implies (using AC) that there is a surjection $\varphi\colon B\to A$. Now we can define an injection:
$$
f\mapsto f\circ \varphi\colon C^A\to C^B.
$$
This is an injection because $\varphi$ is an surjection and therefore an [epimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism) i.e. right-cancellable: if $f\circ\varphi = g\circ\varphi$ then $f=g$. (To prove that: if $f\circ\varphi = g\circ\varphi$, then for any $a\in A$, $a=\varphi(b)$ for some $b\in B$, so $f(a) = f(\varphi(b)) = g(\varphi(b)) = g(a)$.)

By the way, the statement is not true for $C = \emptyset$:
$$\lvert \emptyset^X \rvert = \begin{cases} 
1 &\text{if $X = \emptyset$,} \\
0 &\text{if $X \ne \emptyset$.} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: While you are absolutely correct, the first line points at the assumption that none of the sets involved are empty. Also working with surjections will later require the axiom of choice, whereas the suggested approach in the comments does not.

Comment: @Asaf, Thanks - fixed. I'm only demi-caffeinated, & probably I got snowblinded by the rest of the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A downside is needing AC, ya. I thought I would leave the proof using an injection $A\to B$ to @ Guy.

Comment: i voted it up for finding the hidden assumption that C is not empty.